# Why is Nginx 1.10.0 failing with multiple server blocks?

Tags: ubuntu, nginx

I'm experiencing large problems with setting up a nginx 1.10.0 server on my Ubuntu 16.04 Node.
The first Virtualhost with the Configuration

```
server {
   server_name lukvonstrom.de;

   server_tokens off;

   listen 80;
   listen [::]:80;

   return 301 https://lukvonstrom.de$request_uri;

}




server {

    server_name lukvonstrom.de;

    server_tokens off;

    listen 443 ssl http2;
    listen [::]:443 ssl http2;

    root /var/www/lukvonstrom.de/;

    index index.html;

    add_header X-Frame-Options SAMEORIGIN;
    add_header X-Content-Type-Options nosniff;
    add_header Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=31536000; includeSubdomains; preload";
    add_header X-XSS-Protection "1; mode=block";
    add_header X-Robots-Tag none;

    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/lukvonstrom.de/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/lukvonstrom.de/privkey.pem;

    ssl_session_cache shared:SSL:50m;
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
    ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;

    ssl_ciphers 'ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305:ECDHE-RSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES$

    resolver 8.8.8.8;
    ssl_stapling on;
    ssl_stapling_verify on;
    ssl_trusted_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/lukvonstrom.de/fullchain.pem;

    ssl_dhparam /etc/nginx/ssl/dhparam4096.pem;

}
```

is running with no problems. When I'm adding a new Host in the conf.d Directory in this example it is git.lukvonstrom.de with following config:

```
server {
    server_name git.lukvonstrom.de;

    server_tokens off;

    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;

    return 301 https://git.lukvonstrom.de$request_uri;
}

server {
    server_name git.lukvonstrom.de;
    client_max_body_size 50m;

    location / {
            proxy_pass http://localhost:3000;
    }

    server_tokens off;

    listen 443 ssl http2;
    listen [::]:443 ssl http2;

    add_header X-Frame-Options SAMEORIGIN;
    add_header X-Content-Type-Options nosniff;
    add_header Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=31536000; includeSubdomains; preload";
    add_header X-XSS-Protection "1; mode=block";
    add_header X-Robots-Tag none;

    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/git.lukvonstrom.de/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/git.lukvonstrom.de/privkey.pem;
    ssl_session_cache shared:SSL:50m;
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
    ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
    ssl_ciphers 'ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305:ECDHE-RSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES$
    resolver 8.8.8.8;
    ssl_stapling on;
    ssl_stapling_verify on;
    ssl_trusted_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/git.lukvonstrom.de/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_dhparam /etc/nginx/ssl/dhparam4096.pem;
}
}
```

nginx -t produces following output

```
nginx: [emerg] unexpected end of file, expecting ";" or "}" in /etc/nginx/conf.d/git.lukvonstrom.de.conf:44
nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test failed
```

Is there anyone how could explain me why this error ocurrs?

Thanks in advance,
LukvonStrom

Comment: Error says you exact file and line. What's the problem? I guess it's double closing brace

Comment: Btw, you've got syntax error in ssl_ciphers line

Answer (score 0):

Could you try using different server name. The server name  "lukvonstrom.de" should be unique for different servers blocks.